# I have miss-sync PAL frames (pictures inside)

Tags: stm32, video, decoder

**In some cases I get this picture:**

[image]

**And sometimes I get that picture:**

[image]

analogue camera -> TVP5150AM1 -[external sync discrete VSYNC|HSYNC]-> STM32H7_DCMI

I could correct the second picture with offset and I know exactly what offset I should use, (it's obvious from debug info I gather, the corrupted image just have 368 pixels + 305*800 pixels). So semi-sync data just have 305*800 pixels and I could monitoring this but I still have feeling that I'm doing something wrong. I have no idea where this extraneous and excess pixels taken from. Is this previous (not captured) frame, this frame, ... , etc?

I'am confused right now, I was thinking that DCMI peripheral will do all the heavy lifting for me, but I get this.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Explain what devices you are using and what you intend to achieve

Comment: @AndyWest, https://imgur.com/a/mz9Mi4P. I just want my data be synced.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you're trying to display an interlaced signal on a progressive display. The top picture shows the two fields of the same frame, while the bottom picture shows two fields from two different frames. The horizontal position is affected by which of the two VSYNCs per frame the logic is locking onto.

You need to configure the DCMI peripheral to correctly handle the interlaced signal.

Comment: I assume that my DCMI peripheral hasn't this mode. Any Ideas how I could implement it myself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any details about the STM32 DCMI peripheral. Right now, I'm up to my eyeballs trying to figure out how the HDVPSS on TI's DaVinci chips works.